# Convert Object To array mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document 1: Need to covert object to Arrays. I have to iterate on each element of the key and value, how I can convert from an object to Array.

```
{
  "Data":{
    "A" :{
      "name" : alpha,
      "Score" : 199
    },
    "B" :{
      "name" : Beta,
      "Score" : 122
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output :

```
{
  "name" :[
    alpha,
    Beta
  ],
  "score": [
    199,
    122
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using mongo aggregation framework.

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$Data"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Data"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "_id",
      "name": {
        $push: "$Data.v.name"
      },
      "score": {
        $push: "$Data.v.Score"
      },
      
    }
  }
]
```

Mongo Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVTW5rEoJoa